# compare date to column header value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was creating the vehicle and driver availability chart.

I had a table looks like

```
driver_id    M1_1   M1_2  .... M1_31  M2_1 M2_2 M2_3 ..... M2_31 M3_1 M3_2 ... M3_31
```

it has up to 92 columns.

User will select up to 3 months.

Now if a driver was booked on 25-04-2014,if user searches for availability, the column M1_4 has to have some value say "Booked". Rest of all can be empty.with driver id in driver_id column.
similarly if the date is 25-05-2014 column M2_4 will get value "booked"

and if date is 25-06-2014 column  M3_4 will get value "booked".

When I export this data to excel header with dates and first column with driver and the dates booked will have "booked".rest will be empty.

Can be done by the way I was doing?
Is there Any other was to approach?? 
Please help me out.

Comment: You shouldn't design tables like this. That may be how the data gets *presented* to the user, but it shouldn't be how it's stored. Since the things being stored in the `Mx_y` columns are all of the same nature, that indicates that that should be a single column. And then the `x` and `y` values should be stored in their own columns. So you'd have a table of `driver_id,x,y,availability` and then have many *rows* for the same driver.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what `x` and `y` are or even if it's just a single column, maybe to store a date, because your narrative *doesn't* make it clear to me why, say, 25-06-2014 logically is translated to `M3_4`. Maybe if you gave a couple more examples where the day and/or year varies, rather than just the month, it may be more obvious.

Comment: thnx for ur advise, can you tel me the correct approach..

Comment: user will select three months soo the first month compares with M1 and that month`s date compares with 25 (for 25-06-2014) where you have M1_25,for the 2nd month M2_25 ....